# Laravel command setup into digitalocean cron job but not working

Tags: laravel, cron

In my laravel application under routes/console.php have one command. I want to run this command every minute which is given below:

```
Artisan::command('inspire', function () {
   $this->comment(Inspiring::quote());
})->describe('Display an inspiring quote');
```

In digital ocean crontab i registered below command but not working.

```
 * * * * * cd /var/www/html/laravel_projects/user_profile/ && php artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**N.B:** In digitalocean cron status showing it's active and if i run this command under project directory manually & its' working.

Comment: How can you be sure that the command doesn't run?

Comment: I used some activity under Inspiring::quote() but it's not working but if i run php artisan inspire command under project directory it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a schedule to tell Laravel which commands you want to run.

Your task schedule is defined in the `app/Console/Kernel.php` file's schedule method.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')->daily(); // or some other time
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#defining-schedules

Answer (score 0):

Add task schedule inside App\Console\Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('reminders:send')->everyMinute();
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo service cron restart

execute this command to restart cronjob service